# Sharepoint 2010 Variation site is not working

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am new to SharePoint. I am trying to export the `SiteCollection` from one `SP 2010` server to another in the same local network.

I've imported the backup using `Import-SPWeb -identity http://servername:7777 -path "D:\back up full\31-03-2014\new.bak"`.

The imported site is having two subsites; `http://servername:7777/en` (English) and `http://servername:7777/ar` (Arabic).

The import worked fine and the english site is working fine. But when I access the arabic version it is throwing some error.

Please find the StackTrace below;

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PersonalActions.CreateChildControls() +2054
System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +145
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.TemplateBasedControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +61
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ToolBarMenuButton.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +48
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +65
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2427
```

What could be the reason how do I fix this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Maybe you have Arabic Language pack on your source server? If so then you probably need to install it on destination server as well.

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets that was the issue... fixed it... I shall accept it if you post this as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Arabic Language pack on your source server then it should be deployed to destination server as well in order for restore procedure to work properly.